# Duplicates within 2 arrays

Tags: c

So what i'm doing is populating 2 arrays x_cord and y_cord with a maximum amount of values in each. In this case both arrays can hold a maximum amount of unique elements of 5 and each element must be between 0 and 2. Afterwards once the arrays are completely randomized I am writing the values into a file

It would look something like this:

```
 0 0 
 1 2 
 2 1
 2 2 
 0 1
```

I don't want any of the rows to be duplicates of no another, however I am running into trouble where I am creating duplicates of one another, any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
 for (j=0; j < num_pt; j++){
        (x_cord[j] = rand()%max_x+1);
        (y_cord[j] = rand()%max_y);
         for(m=j+1; m < num_pt; m++){
             if ((x_cord[j]==x_cord[m]) && (y_cord[j]==y_cord[m])){
                    x_cord[j] = rand()%max_x+1;
             }
          }
      }
      for (j=0; j < num_pt;j++){
         fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", x_cord[j], y_cord[j]);
      }
```

Comment: Some spaces in your code will be appreciated

Comment: Move your initial value assignments out of the loop over m. Also limit that loop to only go to the number of value pairs you've generated so far.

Comment: Rather than generating elements and checking if they are unique, generate all elements, then shuffle the elements

Comment: So turn m = j+1, and move the generated values into the initial for loop?

Comment: You really don't need parentheses around an assignment like `(y_cord[j] = rand()%max_y);` — it would be much, much, much more sensible to use the orthodox `y_cord[j] = rand() % max_y;` without the parentheses (and with the extra spaces around the `%` operator).  You don't even do it consistently — you have one instance of `(x_cord[j] = rand()%max_x+1);` and one instance of `x_cord[j] = rand()%max_x+1;`.  Consistency is very important in programming; learn to be consistent now.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than repeatedly generating a pair until you find a unique pair, generate all pairs, then shuffle the pairs.

```
int max_y = 2;
int max_x = 2;
size_t num_eles = (max_x+1)*(max_y+1);
size_t desired_num_eles = 6;

if (desired_num_eles > num_eles)
   desired_num_eles = num_eles;

int* y_cord = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_eles);
int* x_cord = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_eles);

for (int y = max_y; y--; ) {
   for (int x = max_x; x--; ) {
      size_t i = y * max_x + x;
      y_cord[i] = y;
      x_cord[i] = x;
   }
}

for (size_t i = 0; i<desired_num_eles; ++i) {
    size_t j = rand() % (num_eles - i) + i;
    // Swap i and j
    y_cord[i] ^= y_cord[j];  y_cord[j] ^= y_cord[i];  y_cord[i] ^= y_cord[j];
    x_cord[i] ^= x_cord[j];  x_cord[j] ^= x_cord[i];  x_cord[i] ^= x_cord[j];
}

num_eles = desired_num_eles;
y_cord = realloc(sizeof(int) * num_eles);
x_cord = realloc(sizeof(int) * num_eles);
```